# Connecting SharePoint 365

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, credentials, sharepoint-clientobject

I try to connect a sharepoint list using SharePoint 365.

For manual access, the browser is opening connecting to 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com` and I have to Sign In
using my Email-Address - no password is needed. Looks like this:

[image: Signin pattern for login - only my email is required, no password]

Now, I want to access a sharepoint list via `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll`
and generated this code for a first try:

```
    public static class Program
{
    public static System.Uri SPLink = new System.Uri("https://ListToSharepoint.com/sites/Topic/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext Cc = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(SPLink);
        System.Security.SecureString MyPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach(char c in "AtWebLoginThereIsNoPasswordNeeded") { MyPassword.AppendChar(c); } /*If I comment this line, the same error occures*/

        Cc.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("ImUsing.ThisEmail@ForLogin.com", MyPassword);

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List MyList = Cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection LIC = MyList.GetItems(new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery());

        Cc.Load(LIC);
        Cc.ExecuteQuery(); /*System.Net.WebException: 'Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.'*/


        return;
    }
}
```

Executing the code, I get a `System.Net.WebException: Not autorized`

Does anybody knows some help for me? Using the `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`
or `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` also results in the same error.

Links, Username and Password are fake in this posting...

Thanks and regards,
Jan

Comment: when you login from browser and enter your email and click next it will ask for the password.

Comment: to connect through code you've to provide credentials like clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);

Comment: No, it does not ask for a password. And if you take a look at my code, I still use new SharePointOnlineCredentials.